# RavenDB connection issues

Tags: ravendb

We have seen a noticeable uptick in problems related to RavenDB connections. We're using the IIS server connection method.

I've checked the index errors and I don't see anything listed.

This server is replicated with a MySQL server and there is one error related to replication in the log from today. Could the client stack trace errors actually be coming from the replicated server and not Raven?

**EDIT**

The client in this case is a single job that runs a few hundred times a day...succeeding many of those times but increasing in failures due to these errors.

> Sql Replication failure to replication

Here are the partial stack trace errors from the client log:

```
[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context):367
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream():3
Raven.Abstractions.Connection.HttpRequestHelper.WriteDataToRequest(HttpWebRequest req, String data, Boolean disableCompression):7
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectBatch(IEnumerable`1 commandDatas, String operationUrl):171
Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result, Boolean& wasTimeout):35
Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, String primaryUrl, Int32 currentRequest, Int32 currentReadStripingBase, Func`2 operation):169
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, Func`2 operation):33
Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.SaveChanges():65
```

and

```
[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse():570
Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getResponse):45
Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson():206
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectGet(String[] ids, String operationUrl, String[] includes, String transformer, Dictionary`2 queryInputs, Boolean metadataOnly):631
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient+<>c__DisplayClass77.<Get>b__76(String u):51
Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result, Boolean& wasTimeout):35
Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, String primaryUrl, Int32 currentRequest, Int32 currentReadStripingBase, Func`2 operation):169
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, Func`2 operation):33
Raven.Client.Document.HiLoKeyGenerator.GetDocument(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands):41
Raven.Client.Document.HiLoKeyGenerator.GetNextRange(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands):109
Raven.Client.Document.HiLoKeyGenerator.NextId(IDatabaseCommands commands):58
Raven.Client.Document.HiLoKeyGenerator.GenerateDocumentKey(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention convention, Object entity):9
Raven.Client.Document.MultiTypeHiLoKeyGenerator.GenerateDocumentKey(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention conventions, Object entity):174
Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore+<>c__DisplayClass4.<Initialize>b__2(String dbName, IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, Object entity):20
Raven.Client.Document.DocumentConvention.GenerateDocumentKey(String dbName, IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, Object entity):164
Raven.Client.Document.GenerateEntityIdOnTheClient.GenerateDocumentKeyForStorage(Object entity):46
Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.StoreInternal(Object entity, Etag etag, String id, Boolean forceConcurrencyCheck):79
Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.Store(Object entity):23
```

Comment: You're likely to get better help on this via the RavenDB Google Group, or product support channels.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the client cannot connect to the the server.  Maybe the client is offline.  Or the server is.  Or a firewall is in the way.  Or maybe the server is there but blows up before returning a response to the client.  If the issue is intermittent, and users arent complaining, it's probably just a connectivity thing that you can ignore.  If users are complaining, you should look in server-side logs.

Comment: The "client" in this case is a single job that runs intermittantly...shoving data into Raven. This one job succeeds several hundred times a day, but failures are getting more frequent.

Comment: Sounds like a connectivity issue